# UINavigationBar apperance error on device ONLY

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I have a subclass of UINavigationBar class. In viewDidLoad i have:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationBar *bar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] init];

    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"topbanner" ofType:@"png" inDirectory:@"assets"];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];

    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:image forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; //crash here!

    [self.view addSubview:bar];
}
```

And i call it from my tableView. When i run on simulator everything is fine, when i try to run on the device app crash. I have an error:

```
+[UINavigationBar appearance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e3fe490
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[UINavigationBar appearance]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x3e3fe490'
```

Why?

EDIT:
my topbanner file i have in **blue** directory folder in Xcode. In emulator everything looks fine.

EDIT2:
Of course, when i remove this line of code in my device my app looks good to, but there is no image on navigationbar (oc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `appearance` method is new to iOS 5.0. You are probably using the simulator with iOS 5.0, but your device might use a lower iOS version.

It is better to check with respondsToSelector before calling it to modify the appearance using this method.

From the UINavigationBar documentation:

> Prior to iOS v5.0, when used in conjunction with a navigation
>   controller, there are only a handful of direct customizations you can
>   make to the navigation bar. Specifically, it is alright to modify the
>   barStyle, tintColor, and translucent properties, but you must never
>   directly change UIView-level properties such as the frame, bounds,
>   alpha, or hidden properties directly. In addition, you should let the
>   navigation controller manage the stack of navigation items and not
>   attempt to modify these items yourself.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html

Comment: You're right. I use 4.2 device. How can i load an image to navigationBar in iOS 4.2?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:YOURIMAGE forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: When i do that i get: `-[UINavigationBar setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x153af0`

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? As @J_D mentioned, this is only available in iOS5.0+.

Comment: Yes, i understand now that. I'm using 4.2